# Create shapefile containing specific pixels in geotiff

Tags: qgis, raster, shapefile, geotiff-tiff

I have a geotiff layer with height data for each pixel (height range = -3.3 to 67.5 m asl). I wish to make a shapefile that contains all pixels within a certain height zone (4.4 to 4.9 m asl).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Use the **Raster Calculator** which you can find from the menubar `Raster > Raster Calculator` and use an expression like:

   ```
   (("raster@1" >= 4.4) AND ("raster@1" <= 4.9)) * "raster@1"
   ```

---

2. (Optional) - The output of Step 1 will keep all other values as 0. If you wish to remove this entirely, use the **Translate (convert format)** tool which you can find in:

   ```
   Raster > Conversion > Translate (Convert format)
   ```

   Then set the `No data` option to 0.

---

3. Then run the **Polygonize** tool to convert your raster into a shapefile.

   ```
   Raster > Conversion > Polygonize (Raster to vector)
   ```